# A "My Questions" button next to the "Ask Question" button

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, profile-page

Many times I have tried to find the posts I have made and find myself having to go into my profile and look at the Questions section to find my questions.

It would be easier if Ask Ubuntu had a button that takes you directly to your asked questions giving you a list of questions you have asked from your most recent to your first question on Ask Ubuntu.

A "My Questions" button next to the "Ask Questions" button.

I think this added functionality would greatly improve Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: If you do it that often, why don't you just bookmark the relevant URL?

Comment: I could do that but I don't think it would improve the website.

Comment: Ok.. then create a userscript to add such a link.

Comment: Again, you're not really saying why this wouldn't be a good addition to the website...

Comment: a) somebody has to spend time and effort implementing and testing this change, you haven't given any justification for why they should do that aside from "I think *xyz*". You are the one asking for a change, you justify it. I don't have to justify anything. b) Today it's you with your questions, tomorrow it's somebody else with their answers, the day after it's a third user with their comments... All of which can be handled with simple bookmarks with no need for any special buttons.

Comment: My logic is that if you've asked a question, you're waiting for a response. Being able to see your questions easily from the front page makes sense to me. Having the same function for Answers or Comments doesn't seem as helpful as once you've commented or answered a question you're not really waiting for anything.

Comment: If you get a response, you get notified, and the inbox is on every page.

Comment: I upvoded the OP, because I feel it is an improvement for people to start helping others. This site lives from those multi-thousand count posters which I have greatest respect for. This OP IMHO addresses the big broad base of users who have been helped by others and who are *considering* to give sth back. The have no focus on this site (yet), they are tierd to learn to use the 125th forum tools set details. The more intuitive and easy, the more try it out and stick to it. A filter button 'My Activity' beside Questions/Tags/Users does exactly that. I could give examples, but no more space left.

Answer (score 6):

It's not just your questions that would be useful to have fast access to. It's also your answers, and your favorites (i.e., questions you have starred), and the list of all actions that you have done on the site, and the list of all your accounts across the Stack Exchange network, and so forth.

That's why your profile exists and why no page on Ask Ubuntu is ever more than a single click away from it. Note that you may not actually need to view your list of questions. If you specifically want to get to a *recent* question, those appear directly in [the activity tab of your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/current?tab=topactivity), which is the page shown to you when you go to your profile while logged in. However, you very well *may* need to see all of them. I believe you should be able to make your web browser show a clickable link to that page at all times. For example, you can place in a "bookmarks bar." Depending on what browser you use, you may also be able to pin it to your start page.

This is to say that I agree with some of [muru's thoughts](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17457/a-my-questions-button-next-to-the-ask-question-button#comment36272_17457) on this. There's just nothing special enough about user's *questions* that make it so that they, and not any of several other parts of their profile, ought to be linked to directly. There's no reason to think that this would justify a change that might not be useful to many other users, especially since you can use your browser to provide you with similarly quick access to the page. With that said, perhaps it will *ultimately* be more useful to customize the way the Stack Exchange interface is shown to you [through a user script](https://stackapps.com/), though I'm not sure if there are any existing scripts that would give you quite what you want.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that seeing active questions is 3 clicks away.
Having a 1 click solution on the front page makes sense to me.